# A new file explorer window open every time I start CMD

Tags: windows-explorer, cmd.exe, autorun

Every time I run CMD.exe, a new Window Explorer opens.

I already checked the `AutoRun` registry and it's empty.

And I already made a check of virus and malware, but nothing showed up.

My Command Processor configuration:

[image]

And this is what happen every time:

[image]

Comment: Check `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` as well ...

Comment: Thank you, i don't know why but there was "start explorer.exe" in that AutoRun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Every time I run CMD.exe, a new Window Explorer opens

You need to also check the `AutoRun` key in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` as well as in `HKLU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` (which you have already checked).